# XSLT 1.0 select all nodes between 'flag' nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Taking the following XML as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HelloXml>
  <Greeting>Hello</Greeting>
  <Name>World</Name>
  <FriendList>
    <Friend>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <BestFriend id='start' />
    </Friend>
    <Friend>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <Name>Mercury</Name>
    </Friend>
    <Friend>
      <Number>3</Number>
      <BestFriend id='end' />
    </Friend>
    <Friend>
      <Number>4</Number>
      <Name>Venus</Name>
    </Friend>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Friend>
      <Number>7</Number>
      <BestFriend id='start' />
    </Friend>
    <Friend>
      <Number>8</Number>
      <Name>Saturn</Name>
    </Friend>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Friend>
      <Number>11</Number>
      <BestFriend id='end' />
    </Friend>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Friend>
      <Number>12</Number>
      <Name>Neptune</Name>
    </Friend>
  </FriendList>
</HelloXml>
```

I need to accomplish a couple of things:

- Get all the "Friends" that are between the "BestFriend" start/end
  flags (note that they are siblings, not child nodes).
- Make a sequence of all the "BestFriends" that I got there.

The idea is to make an output similar to this:

```
<BestFriends>
  <Friend number='1'>
    <Name>Mercury</Name>
  </Friend>
  <Friend number='2'>
    <Name>Saturn</Name>
  </Friend>
</BestFriends>
```

I've tried using the next-sibling, preceeding-sibling and other logics, but so far, no luck.

Any advise is welcome.

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry, I messed up with an "end" flag. Also, we are using XSLT 1.0.

EDIT: Now the requirement has changed, and it's more confusing than before. The situation is the same, but now the output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FriendList>
  <Friend BestFriend="true">
    <Name>Mercury</Name>
  </Friend>
  <Friend BestFriend="false">
    <Name>Venus</Name>
  </Friend>
  <Friend BestFriend="true">
    <Name>Saturn</Name>
  </Friend>
  <Friend BestFriend="false">
    <Name>Neptune</Name>
  </Friend>
</FriendList>
```

To put the requirement in words, I need to output all the "friends" without discrimination, but I need to add an attribute to differentiate the "BestFriends" from the normal ones. These BestFriends are all of those that are inside the "start/end" flags.

The previous solution provided by @michael.hor257k is really cool and helpful (thanks again man!), but my user changed the requirement :/

I have tried some modifications to the "sibling recursion" approach, also tried some "loops" (but this is not java and of course, it didn't work), and working with some variables (that in XSLT are constants, so it doesn't work either).

Any help is welcome!

Comment: do you want to get all data in bestfriends node ?

Comment: Can you explain why there are several `<BestFriend id='start' />` but only one `<BestFriend id='end' />`? What does "between the "BestFriend" start/end flags" mean if these elements do not appear pair-wise?

Comment: Should friend 3 have `id="end"` instead?

Comment: Also consider to tell us if you can use XSLT 2.0 or are restricted to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I have just fixed the flags, sorry about that... Also, it needs to be done with XSLT 1.0

Comment: Added xslt-1.0 flag to reflect OP's comments.

Comment: This new requirement is not clear. There is no Venus or Neptune in your input. Please provide a representative example **and** explain the required logic in words.

Comment: Just edited to explain the requirement, hope is clearer now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us an indication how many best friends will there be, compared to the total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using XSLT 1.0, and further assuming that your input example is incorrect, you could use the following stylesheet based on a technique known as "sibling recursion":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/HelloXml">
    <BestFriends>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="FriendList/Friend[BestFriend/@id='start']/following-sibling::Friend[1]"/>
    </BestFriends>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Friend">
    <Friend number="{Number}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
    </Friend>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Friend[1][not(BestFriend/@id='end')]" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

```
<HelloXml>
   <Greeting>Hello</Greeting>
   <Name>World</Name>
   <FriendList>
       <Friend>
         <Number>0</Number>
         <Name>Sun</Name>
      </Friend>
     <Friend>
         <Number>1</Number>
         <BestFriend id="start"/>
      </Friend>
      <Friend>
         <Number>2</Number>
         <Name>Mercury</Name>
      </Friend>
      <Friend>
         <Number>3</Number>
         <BestFriend id="end"/>
      </Friend>
      <Friend>
         <Number>7</Number>
         <BestFriend id="start"/>
      </Friend>
      <Friend>
         <Number>8</Number>
         <Name>Saturn</Name>
      </Friend>
      <Friend>
         <Number>9</Number>
         <Name>Pluto</Name>
      </Friend>
      <Friend>
         <Number>10</Number>
         <BestFriend id="end"/>
      </Friend>
       <Friend>
         <Number>11</Number>
         <Name>Moon</Name>
      </Friend>
   </FriendList>
</HelloXml>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BestFriends>
   <Friend number="2">
      <Name>Mercury</Name>
   </Friend>
   <Friend number="8">
      <Name>Saturn</Name>
   </Friend>
   <Friend number="9">
      <Name>Pluto</Name>
   </Friend>
</BestFriends>
```

Note that this assumes there will be at least one `Friend` node in-between the *start* and *end* flag nodes.

---

### Added in response to changed requirement:

> I need to output all the "friends" without discrimination, but I need
>   to add an attribute to differentiate the "BestFriends" from the normal
>   ones. These BestFriends are all of those that are inside the
>   "start/end" flags.

There is a very simple method to achieve that, but it's not very efficient:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/HelloXml">
    <FriendList>
        <xsl:for-each select="FriendList/Friend[Name]">
            <Friend BestFriend="{count(preceding-sibling::Friend[BestFriend[@id='start']]) != count(preceding-sibling::Friend[BestFriend[@id='end']])}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
            </Friend>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </FriendList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have a large input, you may want to consider pre-processing only best friends (or not best friends) first, then using the list to determine the value of the BestFriend attribute on the output.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k really useful input! I tested it online, here are the results: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZXb  Just one more question, you can see that "number='n'" comes from the original sequence, is it possible to start over with a new sequence? Once again, thank you!

Comment: "*is it possible to start over with a new sequence?*" It's possible, but not easy. Is it important?

Comment: I need to confirm with my user, in the meantime, I'd like to "translate" what I understood of the example you shared, please correct me if I mess up: The first template opens the BestFriends tag and goes over all the nodes, applying the second template when a BestFriend-start flag is found and the following sibling is a friend. 
The second template receives the first BestFriend node, prints it along with it's number, then checks if the following sibling is not the BestFriend-end flag, if so, it calls itself recursively to print all the BestFriends inside the flags. 
Did I get it right?

Comment: Not exactly. The first template applies the second template to any Friend that immediately follows a start flag - i.e. any Friend that is the first of a contiguous sequence of best friends.The second template outputs the current best friend, and applies templates to the immediately following Friend, provided it's not an end flag. As it happens, the best matching template for such node is also the second template - so the second template ends up being applied recursively to all members of the contiguous sequence, one by one, sibling to sibling.

Comment: Thanks man, you rock! That's exactly what I've been looking for!